# SQL Server - aggregating and timelining data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample sales data for several items across the years and need to pivot/transform that to weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly groups, i.e, create a timeline for the whole year.

```
ItemNum | SaleDate   | Value 
1       | 01/01/2020 |  20   <--- Week starting 01/01
1       | 13/01/2020 |  50   <--- Week starting 08/01
1       | 27/01/2020 |  10   <--- Week starting 22/01
1       | 16/03/2020 | 100
2       | 08/01/2020 |  20
2       | 12/01/2020 |  20
3       | 05/01/2020 |  30
3       | 09/02/2020 |  10
3       | 29/01/2020 |  40
```

Weeks start from `01/01/2020`, Week 1 = 01/01/2020, Week 2 = 08/01/2020 and so on.
Quarters: Q1 = Jan/Feb/Mar, Q2=Apr/May/Jun and so on

I need to pivot and aggregate the data to look like this -

```
ItemNum | Year2020 | Q1  | Month01| Week 01/01 | Week 08/01 | Week 15/01 | Week 22/01 | Week 29/01 | Month02 | Week 06/02 | Week 13/02 |...| Month03 | ... | Q2 | Month04 | .....
1       | 80       | 180 | 80     | 20         | 50         | 0          | 10         | ...
```

Sales value needs to be listed in their corresponding weeks - so sale made for Item 1 on 13/01/2020 will be shown in Week 2 (08/01/2020) and so on.
Further, the sales values are aggregated at the month/quarter/year they are done

How can I achieve this in sql server?

Comment: Weeks do not align with quarters and years, so your question requires more explanation on how the weeks and quarters are calculated . . . and whether the "year" is the calendar year, ISO year, or some arcane fiscal year.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've updated the question - basically, weeks start from 1st day of year and we need to show the sale made on a particular date is done in which week. Further, we need to aggregate these sales data in months/quarter/year level

Comment: You need your own calendar table - you can find many suggestions on how to create and populate it with simple searching. You do realize that the last week of almost every month is also the first week of the next month (until you get to the end of the year)? Assuming, of course, a particular definition of "week". And you still need to define year and quarter - fiscal year, calendar year, fiscal quarter, calendar quarter, etc. You may be surprised to know that fiscal calendars can be changed.